# Custom button in bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, query-builder

I am using Jquery builder which uses bootstrap-datepicker plugin.Here is the link for bootstrap-datepicker 
https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

For today and clear button following is the configuration.

```
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
  todayBtn: true,
  clearBtn: true
});
```

How can I add custom button to this date picker. Appreciate any suggestion.Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598850/how-do-you-add-buttons-to-a-jquery-datepicker-in-the-button-panel

Comment: @RahulPatel different picker

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910530/bootstrap-datetimepicker-add-custom-button-like-today

Comment: @Ish  I m using a different picker. Actually I am using Jquery builder and it uses bootstrap-datepicker as widget. The link is for bootstrap datetime picker