# Bootstrap: How to add custom button to bootstrap date picker?

Tags: javascript, date, calendar, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to add a custom button to datepicker like today button, I want to add a button bottom of the calendar every month, The **button** name should be "**End of the month**", I have to calculate end of the current month value and display the input filed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#route-from-date').datetimepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            language: 'pl'
        });
        $('#route-to-date').datetimepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            language: 'pl',
            //todayBtn: 'ok'
        });
        $('.datetimepicker tfoot').append('DzisiajWczorajTydzień');
        $('.datetimepicker tfoot th').on('click',function(){
            var $th = $(this);
            var d = new Date();
            var fd,td;
            if($th.hasClass('yesterday')){
                d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
            }
            else if ($th.hasClass('week')){
                d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7);
                fd = d.getFullYear() + '-' + ((d.getMonth()<10)?  '0'+(d.getMonth()+1) : d.getMonth()+1  ) + '-' + ((d.getDate()<10)?  '0'+d.getDate() : d.getDate()  ) + ' 00:00';
                d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
                td = d.getFullYear() + '-' + ((d.getMonth()<10)?  '0'+(d.getMonth()+1) : d.getMonth()+1  ) + '-' + ((d.getDate()<10)?  '0'+d.getDate() : d.getDate()  ) + ' 23:59';
            }
```

`if(!$th.hasClass("week")){
            fd = d.getFullYear() + '-' + ((d.getMonth()<10)?  '0'+(d.getMonth()+1) : d.getMonth()+1  ) + '-' + ((d.getDate()<10)?  '0'+d.getDate() : d.getDate()  ) + ' 00:00';
            td = d.getFullYear() + '-' + ((d.getMonth()<10)?  '0'+(d.getMonth()+1) : d.getMonth()+1  ) + '-' + ((d.getDate()<10)?  '0'+d.getDate() : d.getDate()  ) + ' 23:59';
        }

        $('#route-from-date').val(fd).datetimepicker('update', fd);
        $('#route-to-date').val(td).datetimepicker('update', td);
        $('.datetimepicker').hide();
    });`

more info ([Bootstrap - datetimepicker add custom button like Today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910530/bootstrap-datetimepicker-add-custom-button-like-today))